# Connecting to an FTP server on IPv6 in python

Tags: python, ftp, ipv6, ftplib

That's how I programmatically Connect to an FTP server:
Python code

> ftp = ftplib.FTP (settings.FTP_IP)
>   ftp.login (settings.FTP_LOGIN, settings.FTP_PASS)
>   # ...
>   # here I upload files to the server
>   # ...
>   ftp.quit ()

But just as things with IPv4. But how to connect to the server via IPv6?
I watched some liby, tried to put them in the shell, connect, but alas, it did not work.

Tell me if anyone has dealt with this.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code of `ftplib.py`, it seems to me that the code is absolutely ready for IPv6.

The library knows about `EPSV` and `EPRT` and uses them where appropriate.

E.g.,

```
def makepasv(self):
    if self.af == socket.AF_INET:
        host, port = parse227(self.sendcmd('PASV'))
    else:
        host, port = parse229(self.sendcmd('EPSV'), self.sock.getpeername())
    return host, port
```

shows that it sends a `PASV` or an `EPSV` depending on which IP version we use.